# How can I convert a GDI 8-bpp indexed bitmap to an RGB Bitmap?

Tags: c++, gdi

I am trying to convert an 8-bpp indexed bitmap to RGB bitmap but I haven't succeeded.

The first problem is that the palette returned by `GetPalette()` doesn't contains 256 unique numbers.

This is my code so far:

```
BitmapData bitmapData;
int paletteSize =b->GetPaletteSize();
ColorPalette colorPalette;
b->GetPalette(&colorPalette,paletteSize/4);
b->LockBits(new Gdiplus::Rect(0,0,b->GetWidth(),b->GetHeight()),0,b->GetPixelFormat(),&bitmapData);
char* scan0 = (char*)bitmapData.Scan0; 
width = b->GetWidth();              
height = b->GetHeight();                
stride =  bitmapData.Width*4;               
pBitmapData = new char[stride*height];          
DWORD B = 0x00FF0000;                               
DWORD G =0x0000FF00;                                    
DWORD R = 0x000000FF;                                       
int currentIndex=0;                                             
for(int i = 0 ; i < height; i++)                                            
{                                                                                   
    for(int j =0 ; j < width; j++)                                                                  
    {                                                                                                           
        std::stringstream ss;                                                                                               
        currentIndex = i*stride+j*3;                                                                                                    
        pBitmapData[currentIndex+1]= (colorPalette.Entries[scan0[i*width+j]]&&B)>>16;
        pBitmapData[currentIndex+2]= (colorPalette.Entries[scan0[i*width+j]]&&G)>>8;                                                                
        pBitmapData[currentIndex+3]= (colorPalette.Entries[scan0[i*width+j]]&&R);
    }                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                               
b->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: So can ju describe what goes wrong?

Comment: nothing except that the result bitmap is not correct

Comment: Ok, so what is not CORRECT? Darn pedantic people these programmers... ;)

Comment: sorry but the result bitmap returned is black and distorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
currentIndex = i*stride+j*3;
```

be:

```
currentIndex = i*stride+j*4;
```

given that:

```
stride =  bitmapData.Width*4;
```

also:

```
(colorPalette.Entries[scan0[i*width+j]]&&B)>>16;
```

should be:

```
(colorPalette.Entries[scan0[i*width+j]] & B)>>16;
```

Double `&&` means "if left and right side is true", single `&` means "bitwise and".

Comment: now the bitmap turned to be just blue , this is much beautiful !

Comment: Oh jesus ! what i have done ! actually it become very close , but the blue still the main color , i think now there is a problem with the Pallate , i owe you a bier :)

Comment: What colour do you expect it to be? Red? Sometimes MS images store RGB in reverse order (BGR)...

Comment: yeag but the background is complete black , but it appears in black

Comment: Well, black is zero in all fields, so zero blue swapped with zero red makes zero just the same. I'm not sure, but if you have "red instead of blue", then I expect you need to swap the lines that deal wtih red and blue.

Answer (score 1):

Why the hazel? When you use LockBits you can use PixelFormat24bppRGB as parameter three of LockBits as the system copies the data anyway (you got never direct access to image data in GDI+).

Here some of the errors I found (so far):

```
int paletteSize =b->GetPaletteSize();
ColorPalette colorPalette;
b->GetPalette(&colorPalette,paletteSize/4);
```

Why division by four? GetPaletteSize returns the size in bytes and GetPalette awaits the size in bytes.
ColorPalette is a placeholder definition, one of the darkest thinks Microsoft developers have done to us. It defines only the first color entry!

use a byte pointer like:

```
void *palette=new char[paletteSize];
b->GetPalette((ColorPalette *)palette,paletteSize);
```

Use

```
((ColorPalette *)palette)->Entries[i]
```

When You need to access the color.

Sorry, it is really as ugly as it looks like when you use palettes directly.
Don't forget to free the palette and…
…good luck.

Comment: locking a 8bbpindexed with PixelFormant24bppRGb return garbage scan0

Comment: Thats odd. But thats the reason I wrote the solution below with the palette. I checked the rest of your code and did not find any further bugs on the first look. Hmmm your stride calc looks a little odd, but it should work.

Comment: instead of ((ColorPalette *)palette)->ARGB[i] you mean 
((ColorPalette *)palette)->Entries ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very important that you fill out and align the parts of the BITMAP RIFF format correctly. The palette type bitmap's palette doesn't have to contain 256 entries:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"8  The bitmap has a maximum of 256 colors, and the bmiColors member of BITMAPINFO contains **up to** 256 entries. In this case, each byte in the array represents a single pixel."

The important thing is however that if there's less than 256 entries in the palette, then the bitmap shouldn't index out of the palette structure. Otherwise the source is not formatted correctly.

You want to convert a 24 bpp bitmap. That's a little different than the 8bpp. I advise you to open up an existing 24bpp and 8bpp bitmap files in hex editor, and look how exactly the structures are aligned and what is there, and compare it with your memory layout.